# Doxygen Build failing for 1.8.20 on ubuntu with Clang

Tags: clang, doxygen, llvm-clang

These are the step I follow to install doxygen 1.8.20:

```
apt-get install graphviz
apt-get install bison
apt-get install flex
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/libiconv/libiconv-1.16.tar.gz
tar -xvzf libiconv-1.16.tar.gz
cd libiconv-1.16
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libiconv
make
make install
wget http://doxygen.nl/files/doxygen-1.8.20.src.tar.gz
gunzip doxygen-1.8.20.src.tar.gz
tar -xf doxygen-1.8.20.src.tar
cd doxygen-1.8.20
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -Duse_libclang=ON ..
```

At this point I get the following output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:51 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "LLVM" with any of
  the following names:

    LLVMConfig.cmake
    llvm-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "LLVM" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "LLVM_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "LLVM"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/doxygen-1.8.20/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Now I get LLVM package:

```
apt-get install llvm
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -Duse_libclang=ON ..
```

At this point I get the following output:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Clang" with any of
  the following names:

    ClangConfig.cmake
    clang-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Clang" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Clang_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Clang"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Get clang package:

```
apt-get install clang
```

Get the same error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Clang" with any of
  the following names:

    ClangConfig.cmake
    clang-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Clang" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Clang_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Clang"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/doxygen-1.8.20/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Now What?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was found to be a problem with the llvm and clang that get installed with `apt-get install llvm` and `apt-get install clang`.  This installs version 6 of both.

Instead of these commands, do the following:

```
apt install llvm-10 clang-10 libclang-10-dev
```

Then running

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr -Duse_libclang=ON ..
```

will produce successful output:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.17")
-- Found FLEX: /usr/bin/flex (found version "2.6.4")
-- Found BISON: /usr/bin/bison (found version "3.0.4")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Looking for iconv_open
-- Looking for iconv_open - found
-- Performing Test ICONV_COMPILES
-- Performing Test ICONV_COMPILES - Success
-- Found Iconv: In glibc
-- One (and only one) of the ICONV_ACCEPTS_... tests must pass
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_NONCONST_INPUT
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_NONCONST_INPUT - Success
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_CONST_INPUT
-- Performing Test ICONV_ACCEPTS_CONST_INPUT - Failed
-- The javacc executable not found, using existing files
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/libiconv-1.16/doxygen-1.8.20/build
```

and proceed with `make` and `make install`